# How to set kerberos in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, kerberos

Anyone know how to setup kerberos in hadoop cluster. Are there any tutorials available. I am using Apache Hadoop distribution.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you're trying to secure?  Calls in?  Calls out?  As it stands, this question is really broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CDH4.. it's free and comes with a great Security guide (CDH4 Security Guide).